# dbms_lob.instr Takes a very very long time to fetch the data

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, clob

We store clob data in the database in XML format and the data type is CLOB.

So to get this data we try the use the following query:

```
select message_xml
  from table
 where dbms_lob.instr(message_xml, 'A12345678') > 0
 order by message_date;
```

But this query takes a very long time around an hour or more to give me the result.

Is there a better way to do this.

Kindly note that I am firing the query in Oracle 11g database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes or No your question is to general. The answer depends from many factors. 
You have two easy solution and one more complicated.

1) Trivial function-based index. Works only for one searching value.

```
create fb_trivial index on table( dbms_lob.instr(message_xml, 'A12345678'))
```

and query to utilize this index

```
select message_xml
  from table
 where dbms_lob.instr(message_xml, 'A12345678') > 0
 order by message_date;
```

2) Extract function base-index.

```
create index fb_extract_index on table(extractvalue(xmltype(message_xml),'/path/to/your/value'))
```

or version with namaspaces

```
create index fb_extract_index on table(extractvalue(xmltype(message_xml),'/ns:path/ns:to/ns:your/ns:value', 'xmlns:ns="namespace:from:xml" '))
```

and query to utilize

```
select message_xml from table where extractvalue(xmltype(message_xml),'/path/to/your/value')) = 'A12345678'
```

3) For more sophisticated solution refer this article [oracle-11g-xmlindex-part-1](http://www.liberidu.com/blog/2007/07/10/oracle-11g-xmlindex-part-1/)
and oracle documentation about xml indexing [xmlIndex](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb_indexing.htm#CHDEJEGH)

Comment: The whole issue here is that I do not have a write access on this Database. We only have a read access :(